# How should I think about "multiplicity" for polynomial roots?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, roots

I'm having trouble conceptualizing the idea of *multiplicity* when it comes to finding roots of polynomials. Consider the example from [Multiplicity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplicity_(mathematics)#Multiplicity_of_a_root_of_a_polynomial) on Wikipedia:

> The polynomial $p(x) = x^3 + 2x^2 - 7x + 4$ has $1$ and $-4$ as roots, and can be written as $p(x) = (x+4)(x - 1)^2$.

I understand that, in an algebraic sense, there are three monomials here, each representing a root:

- $(x+4) \Rightarrow -4$
- $(x-1) \Rightarrow 1$
- $(x-1) \Rightarrow 1$

What I don't understand is that, since the graph of this polynomial intersects the x axis only twice, why do we say there are *three* solutions to $x^3 + 2x^2 - 7x + 4 = 0$?

Comment: Perhaps one way to look at it recovering the *missed* solutions? e.g., in your mentioned polynomial, there must be three solutions. But when you plot $p(x)$, you only "see" two of them. Hence the notion of *multiplicity*, which helps to point out that the root $x=1$ is repeated twice.

Comment: You might want to draw the graphs of $y=(x+2)(x-1)^n$ for $n=1,2,3,4$ to understand what it means to be a multiple root.

Comment: If I have a bag with two apples and one orange, I have two types of fruit but three fruit. A cubic with a double root has two roots, or three if you count with multiplicity.

Comment: If you don't mind thinking about it in a more analytical sense, you could say that $p$ has a root at $z = a$ if $\lim_{z \to a} \frac{p(z)}{(z-a)^k}$ exists for some $k>0$; then, the largest such $k$ is the multiplicity. The multiplicity is then "how many zeroes you can divide by and still be well-defined", which is also called the order of the zero. You could then interpret the fundamental theorem of algebra as "the sum of orders of the zeroes is the degree of the polynomial".

Comment: In one sense, multiplicity of a root $a$ tells you how many times you can divide the polynomial by $x-a$ before it fails to be a polynomial / it gets a pole at $a$.

Comment: Another way to think about it is to "disturb" the polynomial slightly. The function $(x+4)(x-1)(x-1)$ is very close to $(x+4.01)(x-1.01)(x-0.9)$, which has three distinct roots. When a polynomial only has roots of multiplicity 1, you cannot disturb it to turn one root into many roots in the same way

Comment: It is not common to say that "*there are three solutions*". It's a lot more common to say that there are two solutions, or two distinct roots, or three roots counting multiplicities. Depending on the context, "*distinct*" or "*counting multiplicities*" may be implied or obvious, in which case they can be omitted.

Comment: @math-physicist thank you, I think that helps. Like, if the Fundamental Theorem of Algebra tells me I can have $n$ roots, but I only have $k < n$ distinct roots, then I need to come up with the "missing" $n - k$ roots somehow, either by accounting for multiplicity or by finding other distinct roots. Is that about right?

Comment: @legionwhale thank you! That is really clever. I need to toy with that, with respect to this problem, to see if I can establish $k = 2$ for the root(s) at $1$.

Comment: @AkivaWeinberger wow! Thank you, that makes a ton of sense! Like, there is something structurally different between polynomials with distinct numbers of roots that should be preserved under small disturbances, and it wouldn't be preserved without accounting for multiplicity. That is really clarifying, thank you!

Comment: @robfrenc : yes, your intuition seems to be correct now.

Answer (score 0):

To reduce the polynomial to a quotient of 1 with a remainder of 0, it is necessary to divide by x-1 twice, hence the multiplicity of 2 for that root.  You were on the correct route.

```
expr = x^3 + 2*x^2 - 7*x + 4

4 - 7*x + 2*x^2 + x^3

PolynomialRemainder[expr, x + 4, x]

0

expr = PolynomialQuotient[expr, x + 4, x]

1 - 2*x + x^2

PolynomialRemainder[expr, x - 1, x]

0

expr = PolynomialQuotient[expr, x - 1, x]

-1 + x

PolynomialRemainder[expr, x - 1, x]

0

expr = PolynomialQuotient[expr, x - 1, x]

1
```

Comment: OP has explained that they already understand this aspect of the matter.

Comment: @MJD Yes, I agree. I just worked the problem through explicitly in hope that the original questioner would realize that the question had been answered by the question's own contents.